# IOS 7 remember this card callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, recaptcha

I am having this problem where we have a payment page that we only allow you to submit once.

And on iOS if you enter a credit card it will ask you if you would like to save it (Safari feature not ours). However this is called after our javascript validation assigns the boolean to disallow resubmition.

The Safari popup stops page propagation and nothing happens.

I was wondering if there was a way to use a callback or hook into when the user submits this value and continue with form submission.

Note: I have already tried `autocomplete="off"` on the form and the input to have this popup not appear. Which does not work.

**Edit:** I discovered that the reason the form does not submit after clicking not now is because we make use of Recaptcha (which is hidden behind the popup in the picture).

[image]

Comment: Try to use formnovalidate, autocorrect and autocomplete all together.

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly I had a difficult time getting the AutoFill dialog to pop up. It seems that Safari needs some type of clue that you're submitting credit card info. If you want the dialog to just go away and you control the name of the form elements, then name the elements to something unrelated to a credit card:

This prompts autofill:

```
<form action="test" method="post" id="credit">
    Name:<input type="text" name="cardholder"  />
    <br/>
    Credit Card Type:
    <select name="cardtype"  >
        <option></option>
        <option value="amex">amex</option>
        <option value="visa">visa</option>
        <option value="mastercard">mastercard</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    Credit Card:<input type="text" name="cardnumber" />
    <br/>
    Expiration:<input type="text" name="expirationdate" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This does not prompt:

```
<form action="test" method="post" id="credit" autocomplete="off" >
    Name:<input type="text" name="h" autocomplete="off"  />
    <br/>
    Credit Card Type:
    <select name="t" autocomplete="off"  >
        <option></option>
        <option value="amex">amex</option>
        <option value="visa">visa</option>
        <option value="mastercard">mastercard</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    Credit Card:<input type="text" name="n" autocomplete="off" />
    <br/>
    Expiration:<input type="text" name="d" autocomplete="off"  />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I'll investigate into it, we have a maxlength of 16 on that field and I would guess that they might look for that too. Upon more searching if you profile javascript on Safari with the ios device attached you can see the internal calls performed by safari after form submission. To give you a hint of what's going on. Thanks for the answer. If it pans out I'll award you.

Comment: Also I can only get the popup to occur in one of our test environments. Not on my local machine. Maybe it is because only that environment has a valid certificate?

Comment: Using SSL may factor in to the equation. In my test I used an https connection.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because you are the only person to post an answer and I didn't want it to expire, I'll mark it correct if it actually works after we do a build today.

Comment: This is insane :) i stumbled across and this popup is only available with valid ssl connection and can't be disabled with autocomplete="off" breaking all javascript events and execution bound to submit buttons etc

Comment: I discovered that the reason this is not working for me is due to Recaptcha, When recaptcha is not enabled, the form performs as expected. Not sure if that helps you Anton

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant on [Sam Nunnally's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105327/945370).

I was in a situation where I was working with a Python package and couldn't edit the name of the credit card, so I had to rename fields on the fly with jQuery. This may or may not work for others depending on how they need to use the submitted form data.

Here's most of the relevant code that worked for me with some comments. I needed to rename the field and detach the label from the input (when there was a label `for` the input that said "Credit Card", iOS sniffed it out), and I threw in `autocomplete="off"` for good measure.

```
var iOSCheck = false;
var cardField = $("#id_card_number");

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) { // This could be more elegant; should sniff iOS 7.x specifically
  iOSCheck = true;
}

if (iOSCheck == true) {
  $("#id_card_number").attr('id','workaround-one'); // Rename ID. Nondescript name.
  $('#workaround-one').attr('autocomplete','off'); // Turn off autocomplete (not sure if necessary)

  $("#w1-label").after('<div class="simulate-label">Credit Card</div>'); // Kill the label. Append the text,
  $("#w1-label").remove(); // Then remove the label. That way the text in the label doesn't link to the CC field.

  cardField = $('#workaround-one'); // Redefine our credit card field so we can reference it later in the script.
}
```